# Error 800A01AD in VBScript on Windows Vista 64bit when create ActiveX object

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, imagemagick, activex, vbscript

I write script in VBScript for converting images. It use ImageMagic ActiveX. I write this script in Windows XP, it's run normaly, the same with Windows Vista 32bit, but in 64bit I have 800A01AD error when trying to create ActiveX object (both 32bit and 64bit have the same service pack installed)

```
Set imageMagick = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")
```

I try to install ImageMagic as Admin (run as Administrator in Context Menu), I also try to run as Administrator:

```
regsvr32 wshom.ocx
regsvr32 scrrun.dll
```

with no success. And also try to run

```
regsvr32 ImageMagickObject.dll
```

Which run sucessfully but script still return error (the same as test script from ImageMagic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the script runs on two 32-bit machines but not on the 64-bit one, it seems like a 32/64bit problem.

A little background: a 64-bit process (Application) can *not* load 32-bit DLL/OCX etc. and a 32-bit process can *not* load 64-bit DLL/OCX etc. files.

I’m assuming that one of the following is happening:

1)  You have installed the 64-bit version of ImageMagick and try to access it from the 32-bit Script environment.

2)  You have installed the 32-bit version of ImageMagick and try to access it from the 64-bit Script environment. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806584/how-do-i-run-a-vbscript-in-32-bit-mode-on-a-64-bit-machine) for a solution for this scenario.